# Cannot get proper expression

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

How can I write the following JavaScript into CoffeeScript

```
foo.bar(function() {
    doSomething();
})(x, y);
```

For instance, the following doesn't work:

```
foo.bar ->
    doSomething()
(x, y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
f ->
    ...
(x, y)
```

is a little ambiguous in CoffeeScript since `(x, y)` is a valid expression on its own. Since things of the form `f(g(x))` and `f(g)` are more common than `f(g)(x)`, the ambiguity is resolved as two statements:

```
f -> ...
```

and

```
(x, y)
```

When the parser resolves ambiguity in a way that you don't want, the solution is to resolve the ambiguity yourself by forcing your desired interpretation with parentheses:

```
foo.bar(->
    doSomething()
)(x, y)
```

That becomes [this JavaScript](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%20%20%20%20foo.bar%28-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20doSomething%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20%29%28x,%20y%29):

```
foo.bar(function() {
  return doSomething();
})(x, y);
```

That may or may not have the same effect as the JavaScript you're trying to achieve. If `foo.bar` cares about the return value of its argument then

```
return doSomething();
```

and just

```
doSomething();
```

can be quite different; the implicit "return the last expression's value" in CoffeeScript can trip you up. One example would be [jQuery's `each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) which will stop iterating if the iterator function returns exactly `false` but will continue if the iterator returns nothing at all (i.e. `undefined`). If your `foo.bar` behaves this way then you might want to explicitly state that `foo.bar`'s argument doesn't return anything:

```
foo.bar(->
    doSomething()
    return
)(x, y)
```

That will become [this JavaScript](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3afoo.bar%28-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20doSomething%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%0A%29%28x,%20y%29%0A):

```
foo.bar(function() {
  doSomething();
})(x, y);
```

and that's exactly what you're looking for.

You could also use a named function instead of an anonymous one:

```
pancakes = ->
    doSomething()
foo.bar(pancakes)(x, y)
```

You still have the possible `return` problem noted above (and you solve it the same way) but perhaps this structure will be easier for you to read and work with; I often refactor things this way if the anonymous function gets longer than 5-10 lines as it makes the structure easier for me to eye-ball.